# Правильный возвращаемый тип функции

Tags: typescript

Есть такой [код](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1pgIQC5oDsCuAtgEYCmATgNwrRFbQQAuZAljgOZWrB1ED2vIEmBxUAvkiShIMAEIAeAMLgoAGmgBpEgE9oJAB4MSOACYwA1tt4AzaEulqAKgD5EScUit4cwBs145oK35FZQg1TR19QxNzSxs7VWgHLQAHEicACmpeIgArbASw6gA6UuZDAghsWDIyMC05COgAH2h5QvDtR1T0pyQASmxkVABtCx1WDW0AXWwvMxxeAHcAqKNTJJ7oAH5bULGZ6GxktLFXVDISBjwyAPwQEDQYYS0xCSDeDJwSJbgM-rUACIwICgcBQbgfm05LAgUQIQARMCGTL9fpUD5fKGwf5qb6-eSw6CA+FqJEo3GQgkwsEQxgsdiooEg9FAA)

```typescript
    class A {
      a!: number;
      b!: string;
      c!: boolean;
    }

    class B<Class, Key extends keyof Class, T> {
    }

    function foo<Class, Key extends keyof Class, Type>(
      obj: Class,
      ...items: Array<Key | B<Class, Key, Type>>
    ): {
      [key in Key]: unknown extends Type ? Class[key] : Type;
    } {
      return null as any;
    }

    foo(new A(), "a", "c", new B<A, "b", Date>());
    foo(new A(), new B<A, "b", Date>(), new B<A, "c", string>(), "a");
```

мне нужно, чтобы возвращаемое значание функции `foo` в первом случае было `{a: number, b: Date, c: boolean}`, во втором случае - `{a: number, b: Date, c: string}`

то есть, мы можем передать ключи как аргументы, но можем передать особый класс, который должен переопределить тип для этого поля, должно работать в любых комбинациях и с проверкой типов и ключей(то есть нельзя выбрать ключ, которого не было в классе `А`)

Comment: жесть какая-то) зачем все это?

Comment: Ну, пример жесткий, но в реальной задаче эта возможность очень пригодится

Comment: Не работает: `class B<Class, Key extends keyof Class, T> { smth!: Key; } type ObjectFromEntries<Entries extends [keyof any, any][]> = { [key in Entries[number][0]]: key extends Entries[infer I][0] ? Entries[I][1] : never }; function foo<Class, Key extends keyof Class, Type, Args extends Array<Key | B<Class, Key, Type>>>(obj: Class, ...items: Args): ObjectFromEntries<{ [key in keyof Args]: Args[key] extends Key ? [Args[key], Class[Args[key]]] : Args[key] extends B<Class, infer K, infer T> ? [Args[key]["smth"], T] : never; }> { return null as any; }` https://stackoverflow.com/q/59996713/4928642

Answer (score 0):

```
// o,o
T1: {
  class A {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
  }
  // - ,-
  type $a<T> = Partial<{ [k in keyof T]: any }>;
  type $j<O, T extends $a<O>> = Omit<O, keyof T> & T;
  // -, -
  const qqqq: $j<A, { b: Date }> = new A() as any;
  // -.-
  const aa = qqqq.a // number
  const bb = qqqq.b // Date
  const cc = qqqq.c // boolean
}
```

```
// o,o
T2: {
  class A {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
  }
  type $a<T> = Partial<{ [k in keyof T]: any }>;
  type $j<O, T extends $a<O>> = Omit<O, keyof T> & T;
  // - ,-
  type $foo = <B, R extends $a<B>>(base: B) => $j<B, R>;
  const foo: $foo = null as any;
  // -, -
  const qqqq = foo<A, { b: Date }>(new A());
  // -.-
  const aa = qqqq.a // number
  const bb = qqqq.b // Date
  const cc = qqqq.c // boolean
}
```

```
// o,o
T3: {
  class Q {
    q: number
    constructor(props: { q: string }) { }
   }
  class A {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
    d: { q: string }
  }
  // -.-
  type $modifier = (new (...args: any[]) => any) | ((...args: any[]) => any);
  type $a<T> = Partial<{ [k in keyof T]: any }>;
  type $b<T> = Partial<{ [k in keyof T]: $modifier }>;
  type $j<B, R extends $a<B>> = {
    [key in keyof B]: R[key] extends new (...args: any[]) => infer Q
      ? Q
      : R[key] extends (...args: any[]) => infer Q
        ? Q
        : B[key];
  }
  // - ,-
  type $foo = <B, R extends Partial<{ [k in keyof B]: $modifier }>>(base: B, replace: R) => $j<B, R>;
  const foo: $foo = null as any;
  // -, -
  const qqqq = foo(new A(), { a: q => ({ q: '' }), b: Date, c: String, d: Q });
  // -.-
  const aa = qqqq.a // { q: string; }
  const bb = qqqq.b // Date !as instance
  // bb.toLocaleDateString()
  const cc = qqqq.c // String !as instance
  // cc.toLowerCase()
  const dd = qqqq.d // Q
  // dd.q // number
}
```

```
// o,o
T4: {
  class A {
    a: { sum: number };
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
  }
  // -.-
  type $modifier<T> = (new (props: T) => any) | ((props: T) => any);
  type $a<T> = Partial<{ [k in keyof T]: any }>;
  type $b<T> = Partial<{ [k in keyof T]: $modifier<T[k]> }>;
  type $j<B, R extends $a<B>> = {
    [key in keyof B]: R[key] extends new (...args: any[]) => infer Q
      ? Q
      : R[key] extends (...args: any[]) => infer Q
        ? Q
        : B[key];
  }
  // - ,-
  type $foo = <B, R extends $b<B>>(base: B, replace: R) => $j<B, R>;
  const foo: $foo = null as any;
  // -, -
  const qqqq = foo(new A(), { a: ({ sum }) => ({ sum: '' + sum }) });
  // -.-
  const aa = qqqq.a // { sum: string; }
  const bb = qqqq.b // string
  const cc = qqqq.c // boolean
}
```